# delphi Activex and parented forms error

Tags: forms, delphi, activex, delphi-xe7

i try to fix up my activex project and i had errors , i have 2 forms in my activex project first form hold `tmemo` and button to call second form as parented form every thing works fine till now but i cannot set any record from second form to first form control always get access violation so i decided to show result before set `tmemo.text` control in the first form and actually result is showing but but cannot be set into the first form here is my project code

```
unit main1;

{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  ActiveX, AxCtrls, embed_TLB, StdVcl, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  Tform1 = class(TForm, Iform1)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }


  protected
    { Protected declarations }

  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure showEmo(L,T:Integer);

  end;

  var
  Form1 : Tform1;

implementation

uses ComObj, ComServ, main2;

{$R *.DFM}

{ Tform1 }

procedure Tform1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Rect: TRect;
begin
  GetWindowRect(Self.button1.Handle, Rect);
  showEmo(Rect.Left + 70,(Rect.Top - 290));
end;

procedure Tform1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Createparented(0);
end;

procedure TForm1.showEmo(L,T:Integer);
var
  Rect: TRect;
begin
  try
    GetWindowRect(button1.Handle, Rect);
    begin
      Form2.FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
    end;
    Form2.Left := L;//Rect.Left;
    Form2.top := T;//Rect.Top - emo.Height;
  finally
    Form2.Visible := not (Form2.visible);
  end;

end;

initialization
  TActiveFormFactory.Create(
    ComServer,
    TActiveFormControl,
    Tform1,
    Class_form1,
    0,
    '',
    OLEMISC_SIMPLEFRAME or OLEMISC_ACTSLIKELABEL,
    tmApartment);
end.
```

**Form 2**

```
unit main2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.OleCtrls, SHDocVw_EWB, EwbCore,
  EmbeddedWB, MSHTML_EWB, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ewbpage: TEmbeddedWB;
    load: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ewbpageBeforeNavigate2(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch;
      var URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers: OleVariant;
      var Cancel: WordBool);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

uses main1;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.ewbpageBeforeNavigate2(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch;
  var URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers: OleVariant;
  var Cancel: WordBool);
  var
  MousePos: TPoint;
  HtmlElement: IHTMLElement;
  iHTMLDoc: IHtmlDocument2;
begin
  if Pos('#sm',URL)>0 then
  begin
    if Supports(ewbpage.Document, IHtmlDocument2, iHTMLDoc) then
    begin
      if GetCursorPos(MousePos) then
      begin
        MousePos := ewbpage.ScreenToClient(MousePos);
        HtmlElement := iHTMLDoc.ElementFromPoint(MousePos.X, MousePos.Y);
        if Assigned(HtmlElement) then
          showmessage(HtmlElement.getAttribute('id', 0));
        form1.Memo1.Text :=  HtmlElement.getAttribute('id', 0);
        Cancel := True;
        Self.Close;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ewbpage.LoadFromStrings(load.Lines);
end;

end.
```

and the question is why i get this error

> Access violation at address 07C734FC in module 'EMBEDA~1.OCX'. Read of
>   address 000003B4.

at this line

```
form1.Memo1.Text :=  HtmlElement.getAttribute('id', 0);
```

why i cannot set result from second form to first form ? what i did wrong here is the full project for better understand

http://www.mediafire.com/download/zn7hzoxze2390a3/embeddedactivex.zip

Comment: I suggest that you do some debugging. Find the code that performs the invalid access.

Comment: i already debug the  project always raise error at this line `form1.Memo1.Text :=  HtmlElement.getAttribute('id', 0);` but i can not find any error with it

Comment: So where is the AV? In the expression on the rhs, or the expression on the lhs. Dig deeper.

Comment: looks that's form1 is not accessible by form2!

Comment: what do you mean is not accessible ? if you can see i included form1 in form2 uses .

Comment: Including a unit does **not** ensure you have a valid reference to an instance in the global variable.

Comment: @SirRufo Yes You are correct private variable can't be accessible into another forms , but this is not a private or public variable its a tmemo control.text

Comment: string in global var working normal but any control inside  Tform1 cannot be set from another form, iam try to debug very hardly

Comment: I am talking about `Form1` variable. There is no guarantee to have a valid reference in that variable just by including the unit

Comment: Why don't you do what I ask, and debug this further? Don't be helpless.

Comment: i try to do as you told me by debugging very deep .. creating break point , added to watch every thing looks normal no real issues has been detected .

Comment: you need to be sure that this form1 variable is accessible

Comment: @SirRufo so do you have suggestion about that ? because i shared all my project and as you can see every thing is there as it is , until iam doing something very wrong , debugging showing nothing .

Comment: @Marthanora whats more than put a form 1 as global var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see this issue once you start to format your code properly

```
procedure TForm2.ewbpageBeforeNavigate2(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch;
  var URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers: OleVariant;
  var Cancel: WordBool);
  var
  MousePos: TPoint;
  HtmlElement: IHTMLElement;
  iHTMLDoc: IHtmlDocument2;
begin
  if Pos('#sm',URL)>0 then
  begin
    if Supports(ewbpage.Document, IHtmlDocument2, iHTMLDoc) then
    begin
      if GetCursorPos(MousePos) then
      begin
        MousePos := ewbpage.ScreenToClient(MousePos);
        HtmlElement := iHTMLDoc.ElementFromPoint(MousePos.X, MousePos.Y);

        // if we have a valid HtmlElement ...
        if Assigned(HtmlElement) 
        then // show a message
          showmessage(HtmlElement.getAttribute('id', 0));

        // now we do not care about if HtmlElement is valid or not
        form1.Memo1.Text :=  HtmlElement.getAttribute('id', 0);

        Cancel := True;
        Self.Close;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

To only solve your current access violation you simply put a `begin end` block around all the lines that will use `HtmlElement`.

```
        HtmlElement := iHTMLDoc.ElementFromPoint( MousePos.X, MousePos.Y );

        if Assigned( HtmlElement ) 
        then
          begin
            showmessage( HtmlElement.getAttribute( 'id', 0 ) );
            form1.Memo1.Text := HtmlElement.getAttribute( 'id', 0 );
          end;
```

But there are some more issues in your code. You should not use the global variables `form1` and `form2`. Instead pass the form instance to the created `TForm2` instance or even better a callback method.

Comment: adding begin and end will define start and end point thanks for this notice , but this wil not solve my access violation , iam interested in the last sentences , `instead pass the form instance to create TFORM2 even better callback`  any example about this ?